# Updates not visible to client after Solr softCommit

Tags: node.js, solr, solrclient

I have a node application which queries and updates a solr instance. Queries all work fine. When I edit an item and submit the update, however, it doesn't show up when I query again, unless I restart the solr server.

I am currenlty running solr 6.1.0 and using solr-node-client http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/

I am using autoSoftCommit configured in solarconfix.xml.

```
<updateLog>
  <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
  <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
</updateLog>

<autoCommit>
  <maxDocs>10</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>300000</maxTime>
  <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>

<autoSoftCommit>
  <maxTime>500</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>
```

I have also tried setting commit/softCommit and commitWithin as part of the update request in the client with no luck.

When I look at the Solr log, I can see the softCommit and hard commits going on the specified cadence, and I can see the changes in the transaction log as well, but they do not become visible to the client until a server restart.

Comment: How are you committing? Your config file show that you have `<openSearcher>false</openSearcher>` - which means that the newly committed index will not be opened and used before something else causes the searcher to be reopened - for example the server is restarted or the core being reloaded. If you don't open a new searcher, the old index will still be served.

Comment: I am also using an autoSoftCommit, which I thought would make the changes visible immediately. In the log when the softCommit is executed the parameters show openSearcher=true

Comment: Could it perhaps be related to the queryResultCache or other caching mechanism? My default solarconfig.xml has  `<queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"  size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own issue. The autoCommit configuration was correct, as evidenced by the logs. The issue was by default the `<enableLazyFieldLoading>` parameter in the `<query></query>` block was set to `true`, so it was not fetching the latest values of the fields. Setting `<enableLazyFieldLoading>` to `false` forces the application to re-read the value of the field.